# parsing each line in text file java

Tags: java

I have a text file that has the following lines:

```
150004|2012|12|15|0|0|3|0|0|-3.2411|83.9962|156.3321|1.1785|205.3125|2.0599
150004|2012|12|15|0|10|3|0|0|-3.4206|85.9575|150.4877|1.4142|226.7578|2.4276
150004|2012|12|15|0|20|3|0|0|-2.2696|86.2675|149.3848|2.1553|225.7031|3.4387
```

every '|' sign indicates it has a column. I have to extract the info from each line that is inside of '|' signs. When I try the following code:

```
File filer = new File("C:\\Users\\Ali Y. Akgul\\Desktop\\150004_15122012_G.txt");
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filer))) {
            while (true) {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                if (line == null) {
                    break;
                }
                String[] fields = line.split("|");
                // process fields here
                for(int i=0;i<=fields.length;i++){
                    System.out.println(fields[i]);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

it gives me:

```
1
5
0
0
0
4
|
2
0
1
2
|
1
2
|
1
5
|
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 76
0
|
0
|
3
|
0
|
0
|
-
3
.
2
4
    at testenv.TestEnv.main(TestEnv.java:31)
1
1
|
8
3
.
9
9
6
2
|
1
5
6
.
3
3
2
1
|
1
.
1
7
8
5
|
2
0
5
.
3
1
2
5
|
2
.
0
5
9
9
Java Result: 1
```

How can I parse it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Path file = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Ali Y. Akgul\\Desktop\\150004_15122012_G.txt");

ArrayList<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file, Charset.defaultCharset());
ArrayList<String []> columns = new ArrayList<>();
for(String line : lines){
    columns.add(line.split('\|'));
}

// Now for each line you have columns.
for(String [] s : columns){ 
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s));
}

// To get only the values for column 8 onwards (in response to your comment)
for(String [] s : columns){ 
    String [] sublist = Arrays.copyOfRange(s, 8, s.length);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sublist));
}

// To get only the columns from line 8 onwards
for(int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columns.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. your solution gives like [150004, 2012, 12, 15, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, -3.2411, 83.9962, 156.3321, 1.1785, 205.3125, 2.0599]
[150004, 2012, 12, 15, 0, 10, 3, 0, 0, -3.4206, 85.9575, 150.4877, 1.4142, 226.7578, 2.4276]
[150004, 2012, 12, 15, 0, 20, 3, 0, 0, -2.2696, 86.2675, 149.3848, 2.1553, 225.7031, 3.4387]

Now how to get the columns from 8 to last?

Comment: Do you want to drop the first 7 values of each array? Or do you want to drop the first 7 lines?

Comment: well I will use them too. but necessary part is from 8 to last. I have to assign such strings for each, so that I can save them on database.

Comment: I changed columns[i] to columns.get(i).toString() because it says array required but arraylist found. THrough my way it gives like [Ljava.lang.String;@6e677ea2
[Ljava.lang.String;@4caaf64e

Comment: nope it still says, array required but arraylist<String[]> found

Comment: For a moment, ignore the comment made by Adrián López and look at the answer - I've edited it and it will work.

Comment: ok now it works, I changed Arraylist to list in the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

It is because that [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) uses a [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

In regexes, the `|` character is a special character meaning `either the pattern on the left OR on the right` of the character. It has to be escaped with a backslash (`\\`)

The correct syntax is:

```
String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
```

Also, take nto that I didn't see the issue with the for loop, but that needs fixing too, that is why the `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` pops up its ugly head...

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i=0;i<=fields.length;i++)
```

needs to be

```
for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
```

(The '<=' must be '<')

Also the issue with your regexp pointed out in other answers.

Answer (score 3):

`|` is a special character in regex which acts an OR operator, you'll need to escape the expression using:

```
String[] fields = line.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `for(int i=0;i<=fields.length;i++){` use  `for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){` so use < instead of <= in the condition.

Comment: and consider to comment of @ppeterka

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have a boundary issue in the following lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<=fields.length;i++){
   System.out.println(fields[i]);
}
```

should be

```
for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
   System.out.println(fields[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

shoud be smaller than: `for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)`